# SMS gone after "failed" boot due to low battery

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, sms, samsung-galaxy-ace, go-sms

My phone has very low battery. I powered it up and during the boot process it shuts off probably due to having no more battery.

Now I plugin the charger then I check my SMS, they're all gone.

I've been this before (being cut off during boot) no major problem and it's only now that my SMS messages are suddenly gone.

Any ideas how to fix this and what probably caused it?